# Editing the output of fslint with shell tools awk | grep | sed

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, grep, perl

The task is to transform this text file, output of the utility `fslint`, into a bash script with `rm` command lines for the duplicate file(s) to delete and commented lines for file(s) to keep, according to a set of rules.

The rules basically say: delete duplicate files only in specific directories.

The goal is to cleanup about 1 TB of duplicates accumulated over the years on several OS (Mac OS X, Windows, Linux). All data has been copied to a Linux drive.

```bsh
#3 x 697,612,024        (1,395,236,864) bytes wasted
/path/to/backup-100425/file_a.dat
/another/path/to/backup-disk-name/171023/file_a.dat
/yet/another/path/to/labs data/some/path/file_a.dat
#4 x 97,874,344 (293,634,048)   bytes wasted
/path/to/backup-100425/file b.mov
/another/path/to/backup-140102/file b.mov
/backup-120708/Library/some/path/file b.mov
/some/other/path/to/backup-current/file b.mov
#2 x 198,315,112        (198,316,032)   bytes wasted
/path/to/backup-100425/file_c.out
/another/path/to/backup-disk-name/171023/file_c.out
```

The first line says there are 3 identical copies of `file_a.dat` and the following 3 lines list the paths to them. Ideally 2 copies should be deleted here. Directories with 6-digit numbers (dates in YYMMDD format) are what I call **historical backup directories**.

The rules, to be applied **in this order** to each group of identical files, are:

1. If a file is in a path including a directory `Library`, keep it.
2. If a file is in `labs data` or `backup-current`, keep it, and delete all duplicates in **historical backup directories**.
3. If a file is in a historical backup directory, keep the file in the newest backup directory, and delete older duplicates.
4. Otherwise keep the file(s).

Here is the desired output:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
#3 x 697,612,024        (1,395,236,864) bytes wasted
rm '/path/to/backup-100425/file_a.dat'
rm '/another/path/to/backup-disk-name/171023/file_a.dat'
#/yet/another/path/to/labs data/some/path/file_a.dat
#4 x 97,874,344 (293,634,048)   bytes wasted
rm '/path/to/backup-100425/file b.mov'
rm '/another/path/to/backup-140102/file b.mov'
#/backup-120708/Library/some/path/file b.mov
#/some/other/path/to/backup-current/file b.mov
#2 x 198,315,112        (198,316,032)   bytes wasted
rm '/path/to/backup-100425/file_c.out'
#/another/path/to/backup-disk-name/171023/file_c.out
```

I'm not very familiar with the shell tools awk, grep and sed, and after reading [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice?noredirect=1&lq=1) I realized my first draft was conceptually wrong, "a naive translation of what [I] would do in an imperative language like C".

And in fact, we're not dealing here with **files**, but with **one file's content**.

Is it appropriate to use a shell script for this scenario?
If yes, how an efficient script would look like?

**Edited:** I tried to clarify the task and requirements, after reading the answer and code from @Ed, which perfectly solves the question.

Comment: No, you don't use shell to manipulate text. It'd be a single awk script.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly the answer I was looking for! After reading more here and there, I was heading to a self-contained `awk` script, but I needed a confirmation I was in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand your list of requirements given how much time I'm willing to put into trying to but here's a script to just categorize and print the types of file you seem to be interested in and hopefully you can figure out the rest:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^#/ { prt(); print; next }
{ files[$0] }
END { prt() }

function prt(   file, isLibrary, isLabsBack, isNothing) {
    for (file in files) {
        if ( file ~ /(^|\/)Library(\/|$)/ ) {
            isLibrary[file]
        }
        else if ( file ~ /(^|\/)(labs data|backup-current)(\/|$)/ ) {
            isLabsBack[file]
        }
        else {
            isNothing[file]
        }
    }
    for (file in isLibrary) {
        print "Library", file
    }
    for (file in isLabsBack) {
        print "LabsBack", file
    }
    for (file in isNothing) {
        print "Nothing", file
    }
    delete files
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
#3 x 697,612,024        (1,395,236,864) bytes wasted
LabsBack /yet/another/path/to/labs data/some/path/file_a.dat
Nothing /another/path/to/backup-disk-name/171023/file_a.dat
Nothing /path/to/backup-100425/file_a.dat
#4 x 97,874,344 (293,634,048)   bytes wasted
Library /backup-120708/Library/some/path/file b.mov
LabsBack /some/other/path/to/backup-current/file b.mov
Nothing /path/to/backup-100425/file b.mov
Nothing /another/path/to/backup-140102/file b.mov
#2 x 198,315,112        (198,316,032)   bytes wasted
Nothing /path/to/backup-100425/file_c.out
Nothing /another/path/to/backup-disk-name/171023/file_c.out
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you Ed. This is really a smart code! This perfectly answers my question. Thank you for your time and effort, and sorry for the confusing rules. I have modified the description of I what I wanted to obtain and the rules to filter the files to be deleted. Hope it makes more sense. I am adapting your (unexpected) great code and will post the result later.

Comment: Yeah, you're right @Ed. After starting to adapt your code I realized my requirements made no sense. I edited the question again.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that gives the desired output mentioned in the question, for people who'd be interested. It's just a tiny adaptation of @Ed's really smart code.

```c
BEGIN { print "#!/bin/bash" }
/^#/ { prt(); print; next }
{ files[$0] }
END { prt() }

function prt(   file, isDate, isKeep, isDelete, backup, latest, pats) {
    # file exists in a current backup directory (yes|no)
    backup = "no"
    # latest historical backup date
    latest = "000000"
    for (file in files) {
        if ( file ~ /\/Library\// ) {
            # files to check manually
            isKeep[file]
        }
        else if ( file ~ /\/(labs data|backup-current)\// ) {
            # backup files to keep
            isKeep[file]
            backup = "yes"
        }
        else if ( match(file, /\/(backup-disk-name\/|backup-)([0-2][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9])\//, pats) != 0 ) {
            # files in historical backup directories
            if ( pats[2] > latest ) {
                latest = pats[2]
            }
            isDate[file] = pats[2]
        }
        else {
            # unclassified files to check manually
            isKeep[file]
        }
    }
    for (file in isDate) {
        if ( isDate[file] == latest && backup == "no") {
            isKeep[file]
        }
        else {
            isDelete[file]
        }
    }
    for (file in isKeep) {
        print "#", file
    }
    for (file in isDelete) {
        # use single quotes to escape special characters in file
        # use gensub() to escape single quotes in file
        print "rm", "'" gensub(/'/,"'\\\\''", "g", file) "'"
    }
    delete files
}
```

Finally, I would like to share some thoughts. I hope I'm not disgressing too much.
A few weeks ago I resolved to finally cleanup that monstruous backup data (some files have more than 10 duplicates). But I couldn't find a tool to automate the task. And I didn't want to fire up a C program for that and didn't want to go the Perl way. So I knew I had to (and I wanted to) go the shell way. But I didn't know where to start and got stuck on the first lines.

After reading a lot, I was still very confused. So I decided to post my question on SE.
When I first read @Ed's code I thought "What the hell!". Then, when I got it, I realized it's a brilliant piece of code, highly efficient and clear.

So here we are. About one week ago, I didn't know anything about `awk` and very few about RegExp. Now, thanks to the @Ed's contribution, I've been able to write "my" first `awk` script, better understand the RegExp world, and complete the task at hand. More importantly, I'm now confident enough dive deeper by myself into RegExp, `awk` and other text processing shell tools. It also motivates me to contribute more to SE.
I just wanted to share my personal experience, and give hope to others who may like me be stuck on a problem, like facing a mountain.